# Dell e4300 Random Beeps

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude

I’ve noticed that my Dell e4300 Laptop will randomly beep every now and then.  The symptoms are virtually identical to the issue described here: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19314488.aspx

Any ideas why?  I thought it might be related to hard drive activity so I downloaded the western digital disk utility and all tests check out fine.

It’s not a big deal and it only beeps once every few days. I just want to make sure there isn’t a larger problem looming. =)

Comment: What kind of beep?  A "system" beep?  (motherboard speaker)  Is it only when you're doing something specific?

Comment: @galacticCowboy It sounds like a set of system beeps.  Does not occur when doing anything specific.  Sometimes it'll happen when the laptop is idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops. Forgot to update this one.  I eventually update the BIOS and reinstalled Windows (as part of a completely unrelated issue).  I haven't noticed the beeps since then.

Answer (score 0):

We're seeing this as well on several E4300 laptops. These steps may have fixed the issue:

1. Right-click on My Computer and select Manage
2. Select Device Manager
3. From the View menu, select Show Hidden Devices
4. Expand Non-Plug and Play Drivers
5. Right-click on Beep and select Disable
6. Reboot the computer

Comment: These steps won't have fixed the issue if its anything serious, they've just stopped you hearing the beeps.